# Custom View inside a Fragment - How to save state?

Tags: android

I have a custom view that draw a Volume wave inside a Fragment that use setRetainInstance(true);

I need to keep the paint object alive when the user rotate the screen, so I think that the paint object must be saved and restored in onSaveInstanceState and restored in onRestoreInstanceState.

Now, I know how to save in the bundle any parcelable object, but I don't know how can I pass the Paint object.

How can I solve my problem?